# Create a table from different resultset and different condition

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table (`ORDER`) let say it is like this:

```
ORDER

typeid  | price  | status | 
  7        8000      3 
  7        8000      3 
  7        8000      3 
  8        8000      3 
  8        8000      8 
  7        8000      8
```

I would like to get 3 result from above table:

```
select count(STATUS) AS TRAFFIC WHERE TYPEID = 7;
```

AND

```
sum(price) AS REVENUE, count(STATUS) AS SUBSCRIBER FROM CMSORDER WHERE TYPEID = 7 AND status = 8 ;
```

what is the syntax to combine 2 code above? So I can get this table:

```
traffic  | revenue  | subscriber
  4         8000          1
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The magic you are looking for is the GROUP BY clause:

```
select count(ORDER.STATUS) AS TRAFFIC 
sum(ORDER.price) AS REVENUE, 
count(ORDER.STATUS) AS SUBSCRIBER 
FROM CMSORDER, ORDER 
WHERE CMSORDER.TYPEID = ORDER.TYPEID 
AND CMSORDER.status = 8 
AND ORDER.TYPEID = 7
GROUP BY ORDER.STATUS;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it can be like this -

```
SELECT count(if(typeid = 7, 1, null)) TRAFFIC,
  sum(if(TYPEID = 7 AND status = 8, price, null)) AS REVENUE,
  count(if(TYPEID = 7 AND status = 8, STATUS, null)) AS SUBSCRIBER
FROM
  CMSORDER
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  COUNT(status) AS TRAFFIC,
  SUM  (CASE status WHEN 8 THEN price  END) AS REVENUE,
  COUNT(CASE status WHEN 8 THEN status END) AS SUBSCRIBER
FROM CMSORDER
WHERE typeid = 7
```